# Get number of records from a match query with py2neo

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

Is there an easy way to get the number of records return from a match query using py2neo?

```
records = g.db.run("MATCH (n:Project) where n.id={id} and ({user} in n.users) return n", id=project_id, user=user_name)
num_records_returned = # how do I do this?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of a query returns a python generator/iterator, as they are not collections after all you cannot know the size/length of it without iterating it.

So if only the count of nodes interest you, you can adapt your query to what Tomaz said.

Otherwise you can use a counter :

```
result = session.run("MATCH (n:Product) RETURN n")
n = 0

for record in result:
    print(record["n"]["id"])
    n = n+1

print("total number of records : " + str(n))
```

Another solution is to transform the iterator to a list, then you will have the `len` function available :

```
result = session.run("MATCH (n:Product) RETURN n")

records = list(result)
print(len(records))
for record in records:
    print(record["n"]["id"])
```

Comment: I was afraid that was the case. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in return statement with cypher

```
records = g.db.run("MATCH (n:Project) where n.id={id} and ({user} in n.users) return count(n)", id=project_id, user=user_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain count nodes in Neo4j, using python driver, use the following commands:

result = session.run("match (n) return count(*)")

total = `result.single()[0]`

**Font:**
https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/sessions-transactions/

Section 4 in "4.3. Sessions and transactions"